# Returning from /bin/sh Functions

Tags: sh

I've written a lot of Bash, but I now need to port some of my code into `/bin/sh`, and I'm observing strange behavior.

I have a function:

```sh
path_exists() {
    path="$1" && shift
    echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n' | while read path_entry ; do
        test "$path" = "$path_entry" && return 0
    done
  
    return 1
}
```

I'm calling it like so:

```sh
if path_exists "/usr/bin" ; then
    echo "it exists"
else
    echo "it does not exist"
fi
```

If I run it with `set -x`, I see that return codes are overwritten:

```
+ path_exists /usr/bin
+ path=/usr/bin
+ shift
+ echo /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
+ tr : \n
+ read path_entry
+ test /usr/bin = /usr/local/sbin
+ read path_entry
+ test /usr/bin = /usr/local/bin
+ read path_entry
+ test /usr/bin = /usr/sbin
+ read path_entry
+ test /usr/bin = /usr/bin
+ return 0
+ return 1
+ echo it does not exist
```

Why is my function not respecting my return codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is my function not respecting my return codes?

Because pipe spawns a subshell, and you are only returning from a subshell. The same way:

```
echo | exit 0
```

will not exit your shell, only exit from `| { the subshell on the right side of pipe; }`. Or the same way `func() { ( return 1; echo 123; ); return 0; }; func` - the `return 1` only affects the subshell.

The behavior is the same in `ash`, `dash` and in `bash`, but I think in POSIX `sh` it would be [unspecified](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_24).

Aaaaanyway:

```
path_exists() {
    case ":$PATH:" in
    *:"$1":*) ;;
    *) false; ;;
    esac
}
```

Comment: Also, POSIX doesn't specify whether any command of a pipeline actually runs in a subshell. I'm not aware of any shell that runs *all* commands in a subshell, but `ksh` runs the *last* command in the current shell. (And `bash` has an option to allow it.)